# Regex for parsing control file

Tags: regex

I have a control file which looks like this:

```
Package: com.jacobcxdev.idunnou
Name: iDunnoU
Depends: mobilesubstrate, preferenceloader, firmware (>= 13.0)
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: Use this tweak to hide, secure, and block conversations like clockwork.
Maintainer: JacobCXDev <jacobcxdev@gmail.com>
Author: JacobCXDev <jacobcxdev@gmail.com>
Section: Tweaks
Version: 1.2.2
Tag: cydia::commercial, compatible::ios13
Icon: https://chariz.com/cdn/icon/idunnou/icon@3x.png
Depiction: https://repo.chariz.com/package/com.jacobcxdev.idunnou/
```

I need a regex to parse for each line:

- The field name
- The field content

The field value must ignore anything between angle-brackets, for example, `Author: JacobCXDev <jacobcxdev@gmail.com>` should evaluate to the following:

- fieldName: `Author`
- fieldContent: `JacobCXDev`

So far, I have the following regex: `(?<fieldName>.+):\s*(?<fieldContent>.*)\s*`. The issue with this is that it does not ignore anything between angle-brackets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the first part until the `:` you could make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

If there can be angle brackets in the field content except when there is an `<` and a `>` with for example at least another char in between that is not a bracket:

```
(?<fieldName>[^:\r\n]+):[^\S\r\n]*(?<fieldContent>.*?)(?:<[^<>\r\n]+>|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<fieldName>` Named group `fieldName`

  - `[^:\r\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than `:` or newline
- `):` Close group and match `:`
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ times a whitespace char except newlines
- `(?<fieldContent>.*?)` Named group `fieldContent` Match 1+ chars except a newline non greedy
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `<[^<>\r\n]+>` Match `<` till `>` with at least 1 char other than a newline or `<>` in between
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SlH1ag/1)

If the field does not contain an opening angle bracket:

```
(?<fieldName>[^:\r\n]+):[^\S\r\n]*(?<fieldContent>[^<\r\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OFSdPC/1)

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing after the angle-brackets, you can use: `(?<fieldName>.+):\s*(?<fieldContent>[^<\n]+)\s*` example here: https://regex101.com/r/kzseNw/1

Otherwise you'll need to split the regex for the field content into another section and possibly more if multiple angle-brackets can exist.
For example of what I'm talking about: `Author: JacobCXDev <jacobcxdev@gmail.com> extra stuff here`